# BlackBerry BrowserField displaying a webpage - detect when user navigates to other pages

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I have a BrowserField in my application displaying a webpage.
Is there a way to detect browser navigation when user clicking on one link in the webpage and move to another webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field/BrowserContentChangedEvent.html

Not sure if this will trigger it however if you look at the api you can see all your options.

Let me know if you find it.

Comment: I will check and report back, thanks for your quick response.